# I am getting First argument "email" must be a valid string error while firebase authentication in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build firebase authentication for my react app.But i am displayed this error after the login button is clicked

> First argument "email" must be a valid string.

this is the function which gets activated when i press the button

```
const login = async (e) => {
        try{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(email)
            console.log(typeof email)
            console.log(password)
            await firebaseApp.login()
            history.push('/daily')
        }catch(error){
            alert(error.message)
        }
    }
```

and this the login function of the firebaseApp class

```
login(email, password){
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```

the strange part is that when i try to console.log the type of email it shows string and it also displays the email and the password i had typed
but still it gives me the error. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: why arent u passing email and password here `await firebaseApp.login()`? (arguments to login method)

Comment: i just forgot to do that...thanks a lot for pointing it..it was so silly

Comment: it's okay, it happens!

Answer (score 1):

Your login function takes two parameters, email and password:

```
login(email, password){
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
```

But you are calling it with no parameters:

```
firebaseApp.login()
```

This means that email and password will be `undefined`, which is not a valid string value.  That's what the error message is telling you.

Pass the correct parameters:

```
firebaseApp.login(email, password)
```